# Python: two integers not comparing as equal

Tags: python

I am making an Eller Maze generation program and am having the weirdest  issue. I have a choice that is a random integer and it's being compared against the length of a single column in the maze, so the program knows how to handle finding the neighbor. For some reason it will not recognize the two integers as being equal. I've noticed a common mistake here is them being different types, I've actively prevented against that by casting them both as ints. Here's the code sample and some debug output:

```
choice = random.randint(0, len(self.unvisited)-1)
        if choice == 0 and (self.unvisited[0] == mastercol[0]):
            choice = self.unvisited[0]
            neighbor = mastercol[1]
            neighbordir = "south"
        elif int(choice) == int(len(mastercol)-1): #<<< THE IF STATEMENT IN QUESTION
            choice = self.unvisited[choice]
            neighbor = mastercol[choice-1]
            neighbordir = "north"
        # choose a random neighbor on the list.
        else:
            neighbors = [(-1, "south"),(1, "north")]
            neighbor = neighbors[random.randint(0,1)]
            neighbordir = neighbor[1]
            choice = self.unvisited[choice]
            print("choice=" , choice, "Len Mastercol -1 = ", len(mastercol)-1)
            neighbor = mastercol[choice + neighbor[0]]
```

And the debug output:

```
    choice= 4 Len Mastercol -1 =  4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Game Stuff\Mazes\MazeGen.py", line 292, in <module>
    NewApp.Run()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Game Stuff\Mazes\MazeGen.py", line 271, in Run
    self.Grid = self.Maze.MazeStep()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Game Stuff\Mazes\MazeGen.py", line 187, in MazeStep
    neighbor = mastercol[choice + neighbor[0]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So in the debug output I can see we're headed for disaster, but those values being equal should have been captured in the elif above, right?

Any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT:

> You are modifying choice right before the print statement. – Selcuk 6 mins ago

Yup, and that's the problem. I was altering the value. I needed to select the neighbor cell first before altering my choice variable. Thanks Selcuk! That fixed it.

Comment: You are modifying `choice` right before the `print` statement.

Comment: Please add `mastercol`, `unvisited` for test your code.